# Store queries in a file

Tags: ios, objective-c, localization

I would like to store my application queries in a file to take out queries from code.

The reason because I need to do something like this is because at my project there is a person that is who make all the necesary changes to queries and send us the queries, then we need to go inside the and look for the specific query and change it.

I was thinking to store all the queries in a plist or a localizable strings so this person can change directly in a single file every query that need to be changed.

But what I am not sure if this could have a performance issue.

Does anybody did something like that?

Comment: Can you show some code on how you are performing the query? And what kind of objects you are querying for?

Comment: I am using FMDB and the queries are simple strings with placeholders.

Comment: There is no reason to localize your SQL.  If I have a column in my local database named Location, to my source code the column will always be Location.  Therefore will always be the same.  In the UI, if I have a label with the text "Location", that would be localized to display the correct language.

Comment: I am NOT trying to "localize" my queries. What I want to do is to put every query in a single file. So if I have to change one, two or ten queries I don't need to search all over my source, instead of that change all the queries that need to be updated inside a single file.